# Use tshark or wireshark to read large file and output only ICMP packets

Tags: filter, wireshark, icmp, tshark

I have a 72 GB file that should have a small amount of ICMP packets in it.  Wireshark cannot load it.  I would like to use tshark or wireshark from the command line to read the file, filter out all the ICMP packets, and write them to a small file that I can then load into Wireshark.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`tshark`](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html) with either of these commands:

- `tshark -r bigfile.pcap -Y "icmp" -w bigfile_icmp.pcap`
- `tshark -r bigfile.pcap -2R "icmp" -w bigfile_icmp.pcap`

The first one uses a Wireshark display filter while the second one uses a Wireshark read filter, but requires 2 passes, although I don't recall why read filters require 2 passes.

In Wireshark, you can also specify a read filter of `icmp` when opening the file.  Do so via *"File -> Open -> File name: bigfile.pcap, Read filter: icmp -> Open"*  This is also documented in the [Wireshark User Guide](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChIOOpenSection.html#ChIOOpen).